# How to block to change formats in preformatted excel?

Tags: excel

In my application, I have a pre-formatted excel for inventory purpose. If user want to change the inventory of some products, first the user have to download those products' details in this preformatted excel and then change some details and then upload the updated excel sheet into the application. This is my working flow with excel in my application.
Here, I have date column in excel and I changed to specific format. So the user must provide the value only in that specified format.
But here, it allows the user to provide date in other formats too. I don't know why and how to resolve this.
It is very helpful if there is a way to block the user to change formats of excel sheet.

Comment: [Protect a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/protect-a-worksheet-3179efdb-1285-4d49-a9c3-f4ca36276de6) protects against formatting cells when `Format cells` is not allowed. But it does not protecting against pasting pre formatted contents which where copied in clipboard before. Erm: What the heck, Microsoft? So the only "solution" may be writing some code which prevents using the clipboard paste function in that sheet. Very ugly this.

Answer (score 0):

Protecting the worksheet will do what you want.

- Select the cells which you want to allow users to edit the value, but
  not the format.
- Right click > format cells.
- On the protection tab, uncheck `Locked`
- Click Review > Protect Sheet. Make sure `Format Cells` is unchecked. Click OK.

Now users can change the value of those cells, but cannot change the format.